# Why does white-space affect ruby function calls?

Tags: ruby, syntax, whitespace

I get a syntax error with this code

```
render json: {
    "what" => "created", 
    "whatCreated" => "thing",
    "htmlOutput" => render_to_string (partial: "some_partial")
}
```

But with this code I don't:

```
render json: {
    "what" => "created", 
    "whatCreated" => "thing",
    "htmlOutput" => render_to_string(partial: "some_partial")
}
```

How come that space after `render_to_string` breaks my rails app?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

the thing is, that method in ruby can be run with or without parentheses.
for example, you can run `Array.new 1,2` and ruby knows that it receives the arguments after the space. and you can also run `Array.new(1,2)` and ruby knows the args are inside the parentheses.

but, when you run `Array.new (1,2)` , ruby thinks it will receive arguments after the space but actually it receives a tuple `(1,2)`, and basicaly its exactly the same as `Array.new((1,2))`

so bottom line:

`Array.new (1,2)` == `Array.new((1,2))` and thats a syntax error because `(1, 2)` literal is not a valid one

Comment: ok, you use my example to explain the underlying issue, but why mark down my answer ?

Comment: Surely ruby could be smarter and not assume a tuple unless that's the expected parameter (arrays are a slightly different question but `render_to_string`? (actually I don't know what `render_to_string` accepts but there are plenty of methods that accept specific parameters)

Comment: its not different, its exactly the same, both are methods

Comment: Yes but arrays could be filled with variable the imaginary method `integer_to_string` could only take an integer

Answer (score 6):

As a general Ruby style guide you should not put a space before the parameter list parentheses. this is not related to rails, but the Ruby language. try the followings to see:

```
Array.new(1,2) # => [2]
Array.new (1,2) # = > SyntaxError: unexpected ',', expecting ')'
Array.new(1) # => [nil]
Array.new (1) # => [nil]
```

As you can see in the second example the code broke, the interpreter was expecting to find a `)` but found `,`. However in the last example it didn't break.

Comment: Thanks. Doh ruby not rails (fixed question)... do you know why though?

Comment: see Dima's explaination