# How to avoid unexpected end of input error when adding extra method argument

Tags: ruby, methods

I am testing a method with multiple arguments.  For some reason, Ruby will run fine if I have just one argument to the `calculate()` method, but when I add a second, it causes an unexpected end of input error.

This is the code:

```
def set_weights
    actual_weight = @desired_weight.to_i - 45
    calculate (actual_weight, 65)
end

def calculate (remaining_weight, plate_weight)
end
```

The error message is:

```
    weights.rb:31: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
    calculate (actual_weight, 45)
                             ^
```

If I remove the second argument, I get no errors.

```
def set_weights
    actual_weight = @desired_weight.to_i - 45
    calculate (actual_weight)
end

def calculate (remaining_weight)

end
```

Comment: you should remove space between `calculate` and `(remaining_weight, place_weight)`

Comment: That worked, thanks! Does ruby take into account white space when calling and declaring methods?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26480823/why-does-white-space-affect-ruby-function-calls) you can get an explanation for that behaviour

Answer (score 1):

Define a function:

```
irb(main):012:0> def add(x, y) x+y end 
`=> nil
```

If you call it without a space between the arguments and the function:

```
irb(main):013:0> add(5,6)
=> 11
```

With the space:

```
irb(main):014:0> add (5,6)
SyntaxError: (irb):14: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
add (5,6)
       ^
from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

The extra space before the argument list causes the interpreter to throw a SyntaxError. Since ruby functions can be run with or without parens, including a space makes the interpreter think it is about to receive arguments for the function - instead it receives a tuple `(5,6)`.

Remove the space and your code will run correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the extra space before the method call, like this:

```
def set_weights
    actual_weight = @desired_weight.to_i - 45
    calculate(actual_weight, 65)
end

def calculate (remaining_weight, plate_weight)
end
```