# Ruby: How can I kill "warning: `*' interpreted as argument prefix"?

Tags: ruby, splat

How can I remove the "warning: `*' interpreted as argument prefix" from the following code?

```ruby
hash = {"a" => 1,
        "b" => 2,
        "s" => 3,}

if "string".start_with? *hash.keys then
  puts "ok"
else
  puts "ng"
end
```

When I run the code above, I get:

```
$ ruby -w /tmp/a.rb
/tmp/a.rb:5: warning: `*' interpreted as argument prefix
ok
```

What is the best way to fix this warning?

I've tried to put parenthesis around `hash` like this:

```
hash = {"a" => 1,
        "b" => 2,
        "s" => 3,}

if "string".start_with? (*hash.keys) then
  puts "ok"
else
  puts "ng"
end
```

then you get:

```
$ ruby -w /tmp/a.rb
/tmp/a.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected *
if "string".start_with? (*hash.keys) then
                          ^
/tmp/a.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '='
if "string".start_with? (*hash.keys) then
                                    ^
/tmp/a.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected keyword_else, expecting end-of-input
```

And this is the problem described in [Why does white-space affect ruby function calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26480823), and clearly not the way to fix the warning I'm trying to fix.

My ruby version is:

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
```

Comment: @AlexGolubenko, this question is about argument prefix warning, not the white space between frunction name and a parenthesis.

Comment: I agree with Yashushi. The main way that people find answers on stack overflow is to google the warning.  If they have this problem, they will not google ```why does white space affect ruby function calls``` because to do that would imply they already knows what is causing the warning. I think the duplicate tag should be removed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're going to use method-calling-parentheses then you **must** avoid putting a space between the method name and the opening parentheses:

```
if "string".start_with?(*hash.keys)
  puts "ok"
else
  puts "ng"
end
```

Also, `then` is rather archaic so we'll pretend that was never there. If there is a space between the method name and the opening parentheses then your parentheses are interpreted as expression-grouping-parentheses and that's where your syntax error comes from.

Once you add the method-calling-parentheses you remove any possible hint of ambiguity as to what your `*` is supposed to mean and the warning should go away.

---

<s>BTW, the warning you're getting in this case is rather, um, silly.</s> On second thought, the warning isn't so silly because Ruby can be whitespace sensitive in surprising ways. This:

```
o.m *x
```

can be interpreted as:

```
o.m(*x)
```

or as:

```
o.m() * x
```

but these:

```
o.m * x
o.m*x
o.m* x
```

can be interpreted in the same ways. Of course, all three of those are interpreted as `o.m() * x` and only `o.m *x` is seen as `o.m(*x)`. Sane whitespace usage would suggest that `o.m *x` is *obviously* a splat whereas `o.m * x` is *obviously* a multiplication but a couple days on SO should convince you that whitespace usage is hardly sane or consistent.

That said, `-w`'s output in the Real World tends to be so voluminous and noisy that `-w` is nearly useless.